# How to keep count of cars in specific lanes by associating car's centroid in a specified area of frame

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I would like to keep a real-time count of cars in each lane, that is, I only need to keep count of cars that currently show up in a video frame. As soon as the car leaves the frame, it won't be in the count anymore.

I am using a pre-trained object detector & centroid tracker to identify cars (python & openCV).
I am thinking of sectioning the frame into areas where each lane occupies. Then, I could check where each car's centroid/pixel lies within the frame. If it lies within the boundaries of an area associated with a lane, increment the counter for that lane. Once that centroid disappears, decrement the counter.

I dont know where to start with coding it. If I could get a guide on starting, that would be very appreciated. If there is a better method to tackle this, please feel free to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are able to detect the cars because you didn't mention about such kind of problem.

Sectioning the frame into the parts seems a good idea if your camera placement is constant not moving.

Using the center of cars and tracking them can cause some problems. For instance, when the program missed the center for a while can cause some problems.

**Suggestion:** My suggestion is that using a track methodology for each car can be a good solution for your problem. You may use this property for other areas in the future also such as speed, location etc. Here is some helpful links for tracking:

[First reference tracking](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/)

[Second reference for tracking](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/23/simple-object-tracking-with-opencv/)

Comment: To clarify, I'm using this article as a reference: [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/12/02/opencv-vehicle-detection-tracking-and-speed-estimation/)   It actually uses dlib correlation tracker to track cars. How can I section the frame into parts? Can I color areas of an image and overlay it onto the frame, then check if a vehicle is within a specific color which corresponds to a lane?

Comment: I couldnt understand your second question. But sectioninig frame is easy if your camera is stable. If you search for *cropping* you can see how to crop a frame.